# Can we force the device to use GPRS instead of WIFI programmatically?

Tags: android, gprs

I am writing code for a *WAP portal*, where I need to have specifically a `GPRS` connection, Is that doable, as far as I know one agregator(O2 uk) has done this type of a trick.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible from android SDK, You can go halfway by turning wifi off but controlling GPRS from app is not possible. But you can ask user to turn GPRS on by bringing up settings page by calling the intent.